# Investigating the stability of a discrete system equilibrium

Tags: dynamical-systems, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

I would like to know which methods or tricks are there for investigating the stability of an equilibrium point of a 2-dimensional discrete dynamical system(f:$\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$)? The Internet provides a quite small amount of information, much less than about continuous systems.

It is clear that one should begin with considering a function $V(x,y)=|x|+|y|$, or $V(x,y)=x^2+y^2$, and maybe $V(x,y)=ax^2+bxy+cy^2$ and checking if $V(f(x,y))-V(y)$ is positively or negatively definite.

The first-order approximation method is also useful in simple cases. 
Sometimes we can also use the fact that an equilibrium point $(x,y)$ of $f$ is stable if and only if it is stable for $f^n$.

Are there any other ideas which can help one deal with hard tasks on equilibrium point stability in the discrete case?
For example, such as investigating the stability of $(0,0)$ (constructing the right $V$), when

a) $f(x,y)=(-x+y^2,y/2+x^2)$

b) $f(x,y)=(-y+x^3-y^5,x-y^3+2x^5)$

(I know the solutions to these ones, these are just examples)

Comment: The first and foremost method for investigating the stability is to check linear stability. If you have a discrete dynamical system $\bar x = F(x)$ and a fixed point $x^{\ast}$, then check eigenvalues of $\frac{DF}{Dx}(x^{\ast})$. If there is no eigenvalues on the unit circle $\Re{z}^2 + \Im{z}^2 = 1$, then the stability can be determined as follows. If all eigenvalues lie inside of the unit circle, the fixed point is stable; if all of them lie outside of this circle, the fixed point is completely unstable (i.e., stable for backward iterations). In any other case, fixed point is unstable.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately, the linear stability method doesn't work in hard cases like these, and it is even not clear how to guess the function $V$ and the answer.

Comment: To some extent this method still applies. If you have eigenvalues outside of the unit circle (no matter, how other eigenvalues are located), the fixed point is unstable. In case if you have some eigenvalues on unit circle and other eigenvalues are inside, you can find [center manifold](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Center_manifold) and take a look at stability along it. If a fixed point is stable along center manifold, then it is stable. This solves problem (a) from your list. For problem (b) there is a method of normal forms, but I can't remember a simple reference for it right now.